# jQuery events priority when element within an element is clicked

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("a").click(function(){
   alert("Anchor Clicked !")  });

  $("p").click(function(){
   alert("p Clicked !")  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href = "#"><p>Click Me ! </p> </a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the link first `alert("p Clicked !")`  and then  `alert("Anchor Clicked !")`  appears.

I want to know this behaviour is observed ?

P.S. : I couldn't come with an appropriate title an edit is welcome

Comment: You can use [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent events bubbling, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/a2Uz3/

Answer (score 1):

This is due to `Event bubbling`

When you use event bubbling

```
                A
               / \
---------------| |-----------------
| element1     | |    a  tag      |
|   -----------| |-----------     |
|   |element2  | |    p  tag      |
|   -------------------------     |
|        Event BUBBLING           |
-----------------------------------
```

Read [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

To prevent `Event bubbling`

use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpYP8/)